# Disregard or replace character in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, replace, datagridview

I have a code to color the cells in a datagridview based on defined criteria for several different pollutants, and it works well. However, there will often be occurrences of the character '<' in cases like "<0.005", meaning "below detection limit", and that crashes the routine with the message "Operator '<' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Double'."

Edit: This is the latest code as supplied by JohnG. I still get error messages when the subs encounter empty cells or invalid characters

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Public Property gridResults As Object

    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        OpenFileDialog2.Title = "Velg fil ..."


        OpenFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = "C:users\<currentuser>\Documents"
        OpenFileDialog2.Filter = "Alle filer|*.*|Excel 2003|*.xls|Excel|*.xlsx"
        OpenFileDialog2.FilterIndex = 2

        OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog()


    End Sub


    Private Sub OpenFileDialog2_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog2.FileOk


        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        strm = OpenFileDialog2.OpenFile()

        TextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog2.FileName.ToString()

        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then
            strm.Close()
        End If

        Me.Button5_Click(sender, e)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Klikk ""Bla gjennom"" for å velge en fil", "Ingen inndatafil")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim FilePath As String = OpenFileDialog2.FileName

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()

    End Sub

    Public Function GetElementColorsValues(elementName As String) As Decimal()
        Dim ULArray(4) As Decimal
        Select Case elementName
            Case "As (Arsen)"
                ULArray(0) = 8
                ULArray(1) = 20
                ULArray(2) = 50
                ULArray(3) = 600
                ULArray(4) = 1000
            Case "Cd (Kadmium)"
                ULArray(0) = 1.5
                ULArray(1) = 10
                ULArray(2) = 15
                ULArray(3) = 30
                ULArray(4) = 1000
            Case "Cu (Kopper)"
                ULArray(0) = 100
                ULArray(1) = 200
                ULArray(2) = 1000
                ULArray(3) = 8500
                ULArray(4) = 25000
            Case "Cr (Krom)"
                ULArray(0) = 50
                ULArray(1) = 200
                ULArray(2) = 500
                ULArray(3) = 2800
                ULArray(4) = 25000
            Case "Hg (Kvikksølv)"
                ULArray(0) = 1
                ULArray(1) = 2
                ULArray(2) = 4
                ULArray(3) = 10
                ULArray(4) = 1000
            Case "Ni (Nikkel)"
                ULArray(0) = 60
                ULArray(1) = 135
                ULArray(2) = 200
                ULArray(3) = 1200
                ULArray(4) = 2500
            Case "Pb (Bly)"
                ULArray(0) = 60
                ULArray(1) = 100
                ULArray(2) = 300
                ULArray(3) = 700
                ULArray(4) = 2500
            Case "Zn (Sink)"
                ULArray(0) = 200
                ULArray(1) = 500
                ULArray(2) = 1000
                ULArray(3) = 5000
                ULArray(4) = 25000
        End Select
        Return ULArray
    End Function

    'Fargeleggingsrutine - gir feilmelding
    Private Sub SetDGVColColor()

        Dim ULArray As Decimal()
        Dim curValue As String
        Dim decimalValue As Decimal
        Dim colName = ""
        For col As Integer = 2 To DataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1
            colName = DataGridView2.Columns(col).Name
            ULArray = GetElementColorsValues(colName)
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                If (Not row.IsNewRow) Then
                    curValue = row.Cells(colName).Value
                    If (curValue IsNot Nothing) Then
                        Decimal.TryParse(curValue, decimalValue)
                        ' the above TryParse line will set decimalValue to 0 if curValue is not a valid decimal i.e `<0.005`
                        Select Case decimalValue
                            Case >= ULArray(4)
                                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
                            Case >= ULArray(3)
                                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                            Case >= ULArray(2)
                                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
                            Case >= ULArray(1)
                                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            Case >= ULArray(0)
                                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen
                            Case Else
                                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
                        End Select
                    End If ' ignore empty cell
                End If ' ignore the new row
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        SetDGVColColor()
    End Sub

    'Første svar fra JohnG
    'Fjerde forsøk på eksport
    Private Sub ExportToExcel()
        Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
        Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing
        excel.Visible = True
        Try
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet
            worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDataGrid"
            Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1
            Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1
            'gets header rows.
            For Each column In DataGridView2.Columns
                worksheet.Cells(1, column.Index + 1).Value = column.Name
            Next
            'gets all other rows
            Dim rowIndex = 2
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                    For colIndex As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Columns.Count - 1
                        worksheet.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex + 1).Value = row.Cells(colIndex).Value.ToString
                    Next
                End If
                rowIndex += 1
            Next

            ' Substituted code below that loops through each column with data
            ' then sets the color for each of those columns by calling the SetColColor method
            For index As Integer = 2 To DataGridView2.Columns.Count
                Dim colName = DataGridView2.Columns(index).Name
                SetExcelColColor(worksheet, colName, index + 1)
            Next
            MessageBox.Show("Closing excel: save if needed!")
            'workbook.SaveAs("YourFileName..",)
            workbook.Close()
            excel.Quit()
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel)
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Error")
        End Try
    End Sub

    'andre eksportrutine med fargelegging fra JohnG
    Private Sub SetExcelColColor(worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet, colName As String, colIndex As Integer)
        Dim rIndex = 2
        Dim cIndex = colIndex
        Dim ULArray = GetElementColorsValues(colName)
        Dim curValue As String
        Dim decimalValue As Decimal

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
            If (Not row.IsNewRow) Then
                curValue = row.Cells(colName).Value
                If (curValue IsNot Nothing) Then
                    Decimal.TryParse(curValue, decimalValue)
                    Select Case decimalValue
                        Case >= ULArray(4)
                            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                        Case >= ULArray(3)
                            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                        Case >= ULArray(2)
                            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                        Case >= ULArray(1)
                            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                        Case >= ULArray(0)
                            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                        Case Else
                            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                    End Select
                    rIndex += 1
                End If ' ignore empty cell 
            End If ' ignore new row
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
        Me.ExportToExcel()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()
    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure if I follow what you are asking so correct me if I am wrong. I am guessing the value “<0.005” is a value in a `DataGridView` Cell. If this is the case then you will need to change this “String” value to a “Decimal” The previous code I supplied did not check for empty or invalid numbers before the comparison is made. Since the cell value could be anything, the code needs to check for two things: An empty or null cell value or an invalid number. The error you are getting could be coming from either case.

Your comment

> *How can I make the routine disregard the < character, replace it with "" or replace the entire string with zero?*

In this case when the cell contains the value “<0.005” will throw the error you see because comparing a string to a double won’t work.  Since you state above that setting this value to zero (0) is sufficient, then I recommend you use a `TryParse` method. If the `TryParse` method is given an invalid number it will return zero (0). You could use this knowledge to implement what you describe.

I would recommend you use the same strategy you used to color the Excel cells. I changed the `GetElementColorsValues` method to return a `Decimal` array. This change is necessary if the values in the `DataGridView` are decimal values.

```
Public Function GetElementColorsValues(elementName As String) As Decimal()
  Dim ULArray(4) As Decimal
  Select Case elementName
    Case "Arsenic"
      ULArray(0) = 8
      ULArray(1) = 20
      ULArray(2) = 50
      ULArray(3) = 600
      ULArray(4) = 1000
    Case "Cadmium"
      ULArray(0) = 1.5
      ULArray(1) = 10
                    ………..
```

Now with this array we can compare the decimal values in the `DataGridView`. I used a `Decimal.TryParse` to get the `Decimal` value from a cells string value like below

```
Decimal.TryParse(curValue, decimalValue)
```

Above `curValue` is a string from the `DataGridView` cell and `decimalValue` is the retuned `Decimal` value from parsing the string to a decimal. The whole line `Decimal.TryParse(curValue, decimalValue)` will return true if the parse was successful and false if not successful.

The convenient aspect of this is that if the parse is unsuccessful (like with a value of <0.005) the `TryParse` will set the variable `decimalValue` to zero (0) as you are asking. Simply using the `Decimal.TryParse` will set the variable `decimalValue` to zero when it fails and will set it to a valid decimal number if it succeeds.  This can be seen in the code below which checks for null or empty values then, if not null or empty uses the `Decimal.TryParse` to get the decimal value to be used in the comparison for coloring. It uses the same `GetElementColorsValues(colName)` method used when coloring the Excel cells... you will have to change the excel coloring code also to accommodate the Decimal array… below this method)

**Update Edit to catch BDNULL cells in the data table**

I was incorrect and technically, you CAN have a row in a `DataTable` that contains no column data. So the line: `row.Cells(colName).Value` will obviously throw the error you are getting. I am not saying this is the problem, but that was the only way I could reproduce your error. So the code below checks for these missing columns of data. I changed the code to use `DataBoundItems` since you are using this in your code; below that is the change needed without using the data bound item. Both worked, however if feel that may not be the case if the table is sorted or rows deleted etc. My next question would be why you would read these empty rows into the data table if they were well… EMPTY?

Obviously, you will need to make these changes when writing the grid to excel.

```
Private Sub SetDGVColColor()
  Dim ULArray As Decimal()
  Dim curValue As String
  Dim decimalValue As Decimal
  Dim colName = ""
  For col As Integer = 2 To dgvElements.ColumnCount - 1
    colName = dgvElements.Columns(col).Name
    ULArray = GetElementColorsValues(colName)
    Dim curDataBoundRow
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvElements.Rows
      If (Not row.IsNewRow) Then
        curDataBoundRow = row.DataBoundItem    ' <-- Added Code
        If (Not IsDBNull(curDataBoundRow(colName))) Then ' <-- Added Code
          curValue = curDataBoundRow(colName)
          If (curValue IsNot Nothing) Then
            Decimal.TryParse(curValue, decimalValue)
            ' the above TryParse line will set decimalValue to 0 if curValue is not a valid decimal i.e `<0.005`
            Select Case decimalValue
              Case >= ULArray(4)
                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
              Case >= ULArray(3)
                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
              Case >= ULArray(2)
                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
              Case >= ULArray(1)
                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
              Case >= ULArray(0)
                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen
              Case Else
                row.Cells(colName).Style.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
            End Select
          End If ' cell is empty
        End If ' ignore null cells in data table  <-- Added Code
      End If ' ignore the new row if present
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Changes to code without using data bound items.

```
…….

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvElements.Rows
  If (Not row.IsNewRow) Then
    If (Not IsDBNull(row.Cells(colName).Value)) Then  ' <-- ADDED code
      curValue = row.Cells(colName).Value
      If (curValue IsNot Nothing) Then
  …….
```

Changes to color excel cells method using Decimal value comparisons.

```
Private Sub SetExcelColColor(worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet, colName As String, colIndex As Integer)
  Dim rIndex = 2
  Dim cIndex = colIndex
  Dim ULArray = GetElementColorsValues(colName)
  Dim curValue As String
  Dim decimalValue As Decimal

  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvElements.Rows
    If (Not row.IsNewRow) Then
      curValue = row.Cells(colName).Value
      If (curValue IsNot Nothing) Then
        Decimal.TryParse(curValue, decimalValue)
        Select Case decimalValue
          Case >= ULArray(4)
            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
          Case >= ULArray(3)
            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
          Case >= ULArray(2)
            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
          Case >= ULArray(1)
            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
          Case >= ULArray(0)
            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
          Case Else
            worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
        End Select
        rIndex += 1
      End If ' ignore empty cell 
    End If ' ignore new row
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion, JohnG. Unfortunately, I get the error message "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid." at the line `curValue = row.Cells(colName).Value` string in the datagridview coloring sub.

Comment: You may have to post your code. It is looping through the rows so technically they should not be null rows and if the value is null or invalid it simply does not color it.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is because I did not use a data bound `DataGridView` as you are. The code needs to get the data bound item from the data table for that cell to check its value. Let me make some changes to accommodate but you can look up getting the data bound item as this is the problem IMHO.

Comment: I think you're right. Many of my former problems seem to be more easily solvable in data bound grids. Would it be better to import the data into a database, or would that generate a lot more work?

Comment: I'm just gonna have to go to code school, I guess ... ;)

Comment: @LarsS I have run the code with the `DataGridView` data source set to a data table. I set up two buttons, one to run your supplied code and another that uses the `DataBoundItem` for the rows and both worked! I posted the changes to get the data bound item line of code in my answer... see it helps. If not you may want to take a closer look at the data table.

Answer (score 0):

The error you report is nothing to do with the presence of "<" in your string. It's because you're trying to an actual less-than comparison on a null value. That's invalid - there's no value to compare. You need to check whether the field is null before you perform the operation, and do something else instead:

```
If Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Cd (Kadmium)").Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
'continue with the comparisons
Else
'do something else
End If
```

However, you're right, the presence of "<" will also cause a problem when trying to cast the value to a Double for the comparison.

For that you can do a simple string replacement, e.g.

```
Dim val = Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Cd (Kadmium)").Value.ToString().Replace("<", "")
Dim dVal = Convert.ToDouble(val)

If  dVal < Ul1Cd Then
'etc
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. However, I get an error using a replace string: "Public member 'Replace' on type 'Double' not found." Is there another replace mechanism that works on type double?

Comment: `CDbl(Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Cd (Kadmium)").Value.ToString().Replace("<", ""))`. May give you what you are after @LarsS.

Comment: @Bugs good point. Have added this. And also how to convert back to a Double for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Also check your second loop:

```
   For i As Double = 0 To Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
```

you only need

```
for i = 0 To Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
```

since you declared it before and as double?
Also make sure to set option strict on and infer to off in project compile options.

Comment: That's not exactly how `For[...]To` statements work. The `i` in the second loop is not linked to the first loop (unless of course the are nested but that would then throw a compile error). That being said, I'm not sure why it's declared as `Integer` in the first loop and then `Double` in the second. I _assume_ it should be `Double` in both.